# Evento hover sólo cuando no exista la sesión $_SESSION

Tags: php, html, jquery, session

Deseo que se cambie el texto del botón **Reservar** pasando de "**Reservar**" a "**Logueate**" siempre y cuando NO exista una **$_SESSION del cliente.**

- Si existe la sesión, siempre el botón con id #reservar, tendrá el
  texto "Reservar".
- Si NO existe la sesión, el texto del botón con id #reservar, se
  cambia.

El problema es que siempre me sale el cambio de texto, aunque existae la sesión.

**Código HTML/PHP:**

```
<?php
    include_once "Clases/BD.php";

    //Iniciar una nueva sesión o reanudar la existente.
    session_start();

    //Si existe la sesión "cliente"..., la guardamos en una variable.
    if (isset($_SESSION['cliente'])){
        $cliente = $_SESSION['cliente'];
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Reservar</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body background="imagenes/fondo_campo1.jpg">
        <div class="sesion_cliente">
            <?php 
            //Si existe la sesión "cliente"...
            if(isset($_SESSION['cliente'])){
                echo "<p class='negrita'>Bienvenido <a href='menu_cliente.php?nueva=1#nueva'>".$cliente."</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;";
                echo "<a href='index.php?salir=1'>Salir</a></p>";
                //Si existe y hemos pulsado el link "Salir"...
                if(isset($_REQUEST["salir"])){
                    //Borramos o destruimos la sesión "cliente".
                    unset($_SESSION["cliente"]);
                    //Redireccionamos a la página "iniciar_sesion_cliente.php" en 0 segundos.
                    header("Refresh:0; url=iniciar_sesion_cliente.php");
                }
            }
            ?>
        </div>

        <div id="contenedor">
            <div class="busqueda">
                <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" name="mibusqueda" id="mibusqueda" method="POST">
                    <h2>RESERVAR</h2>
                    <label for="check_in"><b>Entrada:</b></label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Fecha de entrada" name="check_in" id="check_in" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['check_in'])){ echo $_POST['check_in']; }?>">

                    <label for="check_out"><b>Salida:</b></label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Fecha de salida" name="check_out" id="check_out" onchange="calculoNoches();" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['check_out'])){ echo $_POST['check_out']; }?>" disabled>

                    <div align="center">
                        <input type="submit" value="Buscar" name="buscar" id="buscar"><br/>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>

            <div class="mostrar_cabanas">
                <?php
                //Si pulsamos el botón "buscar"...
                if(isset($_POST["buscar"])){
                    //Código innecesario...
                    echo "<form action='confirmacion_reserva.php' method='POST' name='mireserva'>";
                        echo "<center><input type='submit' name='reservar' id='reservar' value='Reservar'/></center>";
                    echo "</form>";
                    //Código innecesario...
                }
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Código jQuery:**

```
//Al cargar la página... ejecutamos código jQuery.
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#reservar').hover(function(){
        $(this).val("Logueate");
    }, function() {
        $(this).val("Reservar");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías hacer las siguientes modificaciones:

- En `PHP` podrías comprobar si la sesión **NO** existe y en ese caso agregar una clase (`ej: login`) al `<input id="reservar`. Así por ejemplo:

  ```
  <?php

  //Si pulsamos el botón "buscar"...
  if (isset($_POST["buscar"])) {

      //Código innecesario...
      echo "<form action='confirmacion_reserva.php' method='POST' name='mireserva'>";

      // AQUI agregamos la lógica para detectar si esta o no iniciada la sesión
      $className = '';
      if (!isset($_SESSION['cliente'])) {
          // Si NO existe la sesión "cliente"...
          $className = 'class="login"';
      }

      echo "<center><input type='submit' name='reservar' id='reservar' value='Reservar' $className/></center>";
      echo "</form>";
      //Código innecesario...
  } ?>
  ```
- Luego en `JS` deberías buscar solo al `<input id="reservar"` con clase `login`. Así por ejemplo:

  ```
  //Al cargar la página... ejecutamos código jQuery.
  $(function(){
      // Este código solo funciona cuando el `input#reservar` tenga 
     // la clase `login`, es decir, cuando no este iniciada la sesión
      $('#reservar.login').hover(function(){
          $(this).val("Logueate");
      }, function() {
          $(this).val("Reservar");
      });
  });
  ```

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo bien tu problema, de hecho no entiendo tampoco ese JQuery. cuando pasas sobre el botón cambia el texto del botón, si tienes la sesiona controlada con la variable `cliente(isset($_SESSION['cliente']))` y siempre debe encontrarse el botón con el mismo texto por que no imprimes el botón con el texto que necesites utilizando la variable como condición para esto.

```
<?php
                //Si pulsamos el botón "buscar"...
                if(isset($_POST["buscar"])){

//VARIABLE QUE CONTROLA EL TEXTO DEL BOTON
$texto_boton = (isset($_SESSION['cliente']) ? 'Reservar' : 'Logueate');

                    //Código innecesario...
                    echo "<form action='confirmacion_reserva.php' method='POST' name='mireserva'>";
                        echo "<center><input type='submit' name='reservar' id='reservar' value='".$texto_boton."'/></center>";
                    echo "</form>";
                    //Código innecesario...
                }
                ?>
```

Comment: Disculpa, stack me corto el comentario.

$texto_btn = ( isset($_SESSION['cliente'])  ? 'Reservar' : 'Logueate' );

echo "<form action='confirmacion_reserva.php' method='POST' name='mireserva'>";
                        echo "<center><input type='submit' name='reservar' id='reservar' value='".$texto_btn."'/></center>";
                    echo "</form>";

Comment: @Federico No es del todo correcto, debido a que debe cambiarse el texto al pasar el ratón por encima si NO existe una sesión, no debe ser fijo el texto. Debe añadirse el eventon "hover".

Comment: Solamente edite la respuesta, por el formato. @esteban03, formulo dicha respuesta. Saludos